# Music daypart database design

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have made a multizone music player (using C# and SQL) that plays music in sereval zones in the company that I work. Different predefined playlists are automatically loaded at scheduled times.

I am now looking to make the playlists a little smarter. I want to be able to connect a song to one or several dayparts (i.e morning, noon, night).

What I am looking to achieve is to generate playlists "on the fly" at spesific times every day, instead of using the predfined playlists. This way adding songs to my music library making sure to set the "allowed" dayparts will be enough...no more sitting down for hours setting up playlists...

I currently have a music table, a playlist table and a table that connects these two tables to store the actual playlists.

I have a tendency to make things overly complicated so I thought I would ask you guys for some tips on how to design the database in an efficient way... (and maybe a couple of lines of c# code on how to create the playlists)

Comment: are you saying you want to tag a particular song with a "daypart". Can a song have multiple dayparts? Why not use inbuilt MP3 tagging to store this on the actual file?

Comment: Yes and yes a song can have multiple dayparts. I want to keep all this data in the database in case I have to replace/restore music files...

Comment: You could store a byte with each bit standing for one allowed daypart. Ot a string with x letters, each for one daypart. Another daypart table sounds like overkill to me; sometimes de-normalization is the way to go.. - I wouldn't call it 'daypart' though but maybe 'occasion' to allow maybe 'festive', 'solemn', 'seasonal' etc..

Comment: I agree...daypart is not the correct word. I like the way you are thinking...would make the solution pretty dynamic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really interesting problem to deal with. If you want to generate the playlist on the fly then I think the playlist table is obsolete.

What I would do is add 3 more columns to the music table: Day, Afternoon and Night.
These columns stores the chances that the song could be played during the day, afternoon or night.

Example:

```
Day | Afternoon| Night
10  | 40       | 50
```

Then you can do a simple query to generate the list on the fly.

Example:

```
Morning playlist
Select * from SongTable order by Day * random() limit PLAYLIST_SIZE
```

*I am in my office so didn't have chance to test the query. Hint: random number could be generated by:

`ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 100`

Comment: This is defenitly a way of doing it! However I think I would like the dayparts to be dynamic...I might want to add more dayparts at a later time (I know that dayparts might be the wrong word here)

Comment: An easy way to look at it to a JSON field.

{"Day": 30, "Noon": 30, "Night": 40}

Doing it this way you can dynamically extend the dayparts. Just that there won't be any easy way to query for playlist. You have to query for the whole songTable then sort and limit using C#